# Normed Vectors Spaces

Tags: general-topology, continuity, normed-spaces

Let $(E,\| \cdot \|_E)$ and $(F,\| \cdot \|_F)$ be two normed vector spaces over $\mathbb{C}$ and let $u: E\rightarrow F$ be a linear map. 
(a). Prove that the following conditions are equivalent:
i. $u$ is continuous,
ii. $u$ is continuous at $0$,
iii.There exists a constant $C \geq 0$ such that $||u(x)||_F \leq C . ||x||_E$.

(b). Assume now that $E$ is finite dimension. Prove that any linear map $u:E \rightarrow F$ is continuous.

This is what I have tried to do, but I still have a problem in part (a)(i)  and part(b). Can any one help me to solve for those parts?

This is my solution;
$(i)\implies (ii)$
Let  $u:E \rightarrow F$ be linear and continuous.
We want to show that $u$ is continuous at the origin.
Let $\{ x_n \}_{n=1}^{\infty}\subset E$ such that $x_n \xrightarrow{n \rightarrow \infty} 0$ .
Since $u$ is continuous, it implies that $u(x_n) \xrightarrow{n\rightarrow \infty} u(0)$ .
But $u$ is linear implies $u(0)=0$. Then  $u(x_n) \xrightarrow{n\rightarrow \infty} u(0)=0$  and $u(x_n) \xrightarrow{n\rightarrow \infty} 0.$
Therefore $u$ is continuous at 0.

and

$(ii)\implies (iii)$
We want to show that  $\exists c$ which is constant, such that $$||u(x)||_F\geq c ||x||_E \forall x\in E$$
Since $u$ is continuous at $0$ then $\{ x_n \}_{n=1}^{\infty}\subset E$ such that  $x_n \xrightarrow{n \rightarrow \infty} 0$, we can proof by contradiction;

Assume that $\nexists c\geq 0$
Then for any $n\in \mathbb{N}$, $\exists x_n = x(n)\in E \,\,;\,\,x_n= x(n)\neq 0$ such that $$||u(x_n)||>n||x_n||$$
This implies that \begin{eqnarray}
 \frac{||u(x_n)|| }{n||x_n||}>1
 \end{eqnarray}
Consider the sequence $\{v_n\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$, where $v_n=\frac{x_n}{n||x_n||}$, then $v_n \xrightarrow{n\rightarrow \infty} 0$
Since $||v_n -0||=\Big|\Big|\frac{x_n}{n||x_n||}\Big|\Big|=\frac{1}{n}\frac{||x_n||}{||x_n||}=\frac{1}{n}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow \infty}0$
This implies that  $v_n -0=0 \implies v_n=0\,\,\text{as $n \rightarrow \infty$}$
Then from eqn(1)  $||u(x_n) -0||=\Big|\Big|\frac{u(x_n)}{n||x_n||}\Big|\Big|=\frac{1}{n}\frac{||u(x_n)||}{||x_n||}>1$ so that $u(x_n)\nrightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow \infty$, even though $v_n\rightarrow 0$
This contradicts the assumption that $u$ is continuous at 0. So the assumption $\nexists c\geq 0$ is false.
Then there exists a constant $C \geq 0$ such that $||u(x)||_F \leq C . ||x||_E$.

Comment: **Hint:** Use linearity.

Comment: @Lembris: What your thoughts?

Comment: Are you sure that there isn't a line break missing before "assume"? Which implications are easy, which ones are hard? Can you express 3. in terms of Lipschitz continuity?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: the question might be easy to aswer but not everyone has your immense genius, so i don't understand how this could be a reason to down vote.

Comment: @Max Whom are you talking to?

Comment: to who ever was downvoting (i gave +1 to compensate it)

Comment: @Max Before the question was edited, it was 3 lines stating a problem without context, with no further effort shown nor a question on where help is needed. Have a look at the original post in the edit history before offending people.

Comment: but then I don't understand why this question is *still* on hold. it has been edited and is fine now, isn't it? (it's F***ING ANNOYING that ppl put questions on hold because they are not rigurouslely! so ppl who want to help these guys and girls (who have trouble to understand *why* their question is not properly posed) will have to answer questions by *commenting* instead answering because it's been disabled by guys wanting perfect notation.)

Answer (score 1):

You did the hard part, namely $(ii) \Longrightarrow (iii)$.

Now $u$ is continuous means every sequence $ x_n \to x \in E$ must have $ u(x_n) \to u(x) \in F$. Now use $(iii)$ combined with linearity, $(i)$ will be immediate.

Part (b) is also not so hard if you use the fact that every norm on a finite dimensional vector space is equivalent. Try proving it using this fact.